# How to make a Linux program with a TUI

Tags: linux, tui, text-based

I want to make a Linux program with a [text-based user interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_user_interface). What is the best way to go about this? Upon searching the internet I discovered the curses and ncurses libraries. What are the differences between the two, and which if any is better (or is there an even better option)? I prefer C but am open to using other languages.

Thanks

Comment: ncurses is the Linux standard since it is open and free

Answer (score 2):

The `curses` library is an old ATT unix thing, its equivalent free library is [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/), available for Linux and other systems.

You could also use the GNU [readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) library, particularly if you want a single-line, but editable and completable, interface.